# Make HTML table expand to hold contents with no wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have a table which is currently 100% of the window width.

Sample structure: (CSS/styles removed for clarity)

```
   <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Row ID</td>
           <td><div>Some content</div><div>Another</div>...and so on
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Inside each second table cell per row are DIVs containing rows of text. At the moment when the table is rendered the DIV elements flow to the edge of the table and then wrap when they cannot fit.

What I need is these DIV elements to keep in a single row flowing off the screen. I can simulate by manually setting the table width to a large value e.g. 400% but this is often too wide. I need a way to make the table expand to contain the widest row but no larger. Using `white-space: nowrap` only wraps the text within each DIV.

Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/887/ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you just want the div's in a single row, you can use display:inline; About the table expanding to the widest row, but no larger. Isn't that default behavior?

Comment: @NenadVracar Perfect. Do you want to post your Fiddle as the answer?

Comment: @Kake_Fisk The table expands to fit the window and then the content wraps even with display:inline. It needs white-space:nowrap on the td also. I had tried so many combinations I needed a clean answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `display: inline-block` on `div` and `white-space: nowrap` on `td`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row ID</td>
      <td>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, magnam!</div>
        <div>Another</div>
        <div>Another</div>
        <div>Another</div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also had to add white-space: normal to the div to make it render as before.